# Restrictions of irreducible representations of algebraic groups to root SL_2-subgroups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a simple algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $K$, $V$ its rational $KG$-module, and $L$ a long root $SL_2$-subgroup in $G$. Assume that $[V,L]$ is an irreducible $KL$-module.

Has anyone tried to classify representations with this property? They look as a natural generalisation of classical quadratic pairs in sense of John Thompson, or of even more classical classification of groups generated by transvections.

Comment: What does $[V,L]$ mean here?

Comment: The commutator, $[V,L]$ is the span of vectors of the form $v - v^l$ for $v \in V$ and $l \in L$.

Comment: So if $K=\mathbb C$, anyway, this is the unique $L$-invariant complement to the invariant vectors $V^L$? (If your question is easy in characteristic $0$, do say so; certainly I don't already know the answer there.)

Comment: Yes, of course, $V = [V,L] \oplus V^L$ (over algebraically closed field of characterstic $0$).

Comment: @AlexandreBorovik Allen asks you whether you know the answer to your question in characteristic zero

Comment: There can't be many examples. In char $0$ you may as well assume $V$ is irreducible. Then you're looking for representations which restrict with the non-$0$ weight spaces only being $1$-dimensional. The only examples I can think of are $SL_2<SL_n$ and $SL_2<Sp_{2n}$ both on the natural rep. Without doing it, I would guess it should be quite easy?

Comment: Alas, I do not know the answer even in zero characteristics.

Comment: Motivation for this question comes from model-theoretic algebra, more precisely from the theory of groups of finite Morley rank. In certain situations we have to deal with a definable action of a simple group $G$ of finite Morley rank on an abelian group $A$ with a much smaller simple definable subgroup $L < G$ acting on $[A,L]$ irreducibly  (that is, without nontrivial proper $L$ -invariant subgroups) and with  $[A,L] < A$. Notice, there is no vector space structure on $A$ yet, $A$ is just an abelian group. I realised that I do not know answer even in simplest algebraic group cases.

Comment: @David Stewart: It's not quite so easy  (and like Premet's approach it requires extra care for some types if the characteristic is 2, 3).   But see (6.1) in the AMS Memoir No. 365 (1987) by Seitz for the prime characteristic irreducibles.   As he notes, Freudenthal's multiplicity formula indicates in characteristic 0 that classical weight multiplicities tend to grow quickly in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

What follows is not a complete solution: it would take too long to write it down.

Suppose first $V$ is infinitesimally irreducible (and rational) and let $\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^\ell a_i\varpi_i$ be the highest weight of $V$. We may assume that $L$ is generated by the unipotent root subgroups $U_{\pm\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the highest root of $\Phi$, the root system of $G$. Express the coroot $\theta^\vee$ via simple coroots of $\Phi^\vee$ as $\theta^\vee=\sum_{i=1}^\ell m_i\alpha_i^\vee$. Then  $m_i\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ for all $i$ and $\langle\lambda,\theta^\vee\rangle= \sum_{i=1}^\ell a_im_i$. We call this number $n(V)$. Let $X_+(V)$ be the set of all dominant weights of $V$. If we exclude ${\rm G}_2$ in characteristics $2$ and $3$ and ${\rm F}_4$, ${\rm B}_n$, ${\rm C}_n$ in characteristic $2$, then 
it is proved in an old paper of mine 
[here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=905003)
that, as in the characteristic $0$ case, $X_+(V)=(\lambda-Q_+)\cap P_{++}$ where
$Q_+=\{\sum_{i=1}^\ell r_i\alpha_i\,|\,\,r_i\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\}$ and
$P_{++}=\{\sum_{i=1}^\ell q_i\varpi_i\,|\,\,q_i\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\}$. If $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^\ell r_i\varpi_i\in X_+(V)\setminus\{0\}$ has the property that $\mu+\theta\not\in X_+(V)$ then any nonzero vector in $V_\mu$ will give rise to a composition factor of $[V,L]$. The irreducibility of $[V,L]$ then yields $\sum_{i=1}^\ell r_im_i=n(V)$ (otherwise $[V,L]$ would have two non-isomorphic composition factors). This means that $V$ has very few dominant weights. At this point the problem becomes a routine exercise on root systems.

$\mathbf{Remark.}$ 1. If $\mu-q\theta,\ldots,\mu,\ldots, \mu+p\theta$ is a $\theta$-string of weights of $V$, then the above reasoning also shows that either $p=q=\langle \mu,\theta^\vee\rangle=0$ or $\langle \mu,\theta^\vee \rangle +2p=n(V)$ and $\langle\mu,\theta^\vee\rangle -2q=-n(V)$. Since $q-p=
\langle \mu,\theta^\vee\rangle$ this yields that any
$\theta$-string of weights of $V$ either has length $1$ or $n(V)+1$. 
This should narrow the possibilities for $\lambda$ even further.

2. In the excluded cases in types ${\rm B}_n$, ${\rm C}_n$, ${\rm F}_4$ and ${\rm G}_2$ the dominant weights of infinitesimally irreducible representations are also known.
3. The general case, for $V$ rational, can be reduced to the above case by using Steinberg's tensor product theorem. If $V$ is not rational (but still irreducible) one can use the Borel-Tits theorem on abstract homomorphisms of simple algebraic groups; see ${\it Ann. Math}$., vol. 97, 499-571, 1973.

Comment: @Sasha: Just a couple of minor edits added.